# Nested DialogFragment gets dismissed after rotation

Tags: android, nested, android-dialogfragment, screen-rotation

I have a nested(!) Fragment that shows my PhotoNoteDialogFragment:

```
private void newPhotoNote() {
  mPhotoDialog = PhotoNoteDialogFragment.newInstance(this);
  mPhotoDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), PhotoNoteDialogFragment.TAG);
}
```

The dialog pops up, but gets dismissed as soon as I rotate the device. I did already some research and tried these things without success:

- set PhotoNoteDialogFragment#setRetainInstance(true). Does not work, because nested Fragments cannot not be retained.
- Use this code snippet in PhotoNoteDialogFragment to prevent a bug that puts an unwanted dismiss call from the system:

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (getDialog() != null)
            getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

- Try to call the show()-Method in my nested Fragment#onActivityCreated, if the instance of the PhotoNoteDialogFragment ist not null:

```
  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (mPhotoNoteDialogFragment != null) {
      mPhotoNoteDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), PhotoNoteDialogFragment.TAG);
    }
  }
```

None of these attempts could make the DialogFragment come up again after screen rotation.
Has anyone else an idea, what I could try next..? I'm out of ideas.

thx

Comment: Did you use different layout for portrait and landscape mode ...

Comment: How are you adding the root fragment? Are you sure it's retained by the system, or are you recreating it manually?

Comment: @Amsheer: Yes, I have different layouts for the nested fragment as well as for the dialogFragment.

Comment: @BartoszFilipowicz: Yes I am sure that the fragment is retained. When I set a breakpoint in one of its "onCreate"-methods the instance of the dialogFragment is still there after rotation.

Comment: It it's a nested fragment, you should be using child fragmentmanager. Use getChildFragmentManager() for showing the dialogfragment. Also does the parent fragment have retain instance state set?

Comment: Any solution after 2 years?

Comment: Not really. As far as I remember we solved this with a flag variable (isDialogVisible) which is restored after rotation and evaluted if the dialog should pop up. But even Google Apps lose most of their dialogs after rotation...so it seems that it's not something needed for "stock-UX"...

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to override `onActivityCreated`, your dialog is fine without it. I've tried it too. If you show the dialog on `onActivityCreated` your app will crash.